# Remove Horizontal Scroll Bar on Mobile Devices

Tags: html, css, frontend, overflow

I am making a website in which, on mobile devices, there's a Horizontal Scroll Bar that I want to remove. According to a `JS Block of Code`, the overflow is caused by the `.intro` section, I tried adding `overflow-x: hidden;` to it, but it didn't worked! I've been stuck here for two days, I have tried as many solutions I could find over the internet, but none of them did the trick for me. 
**The Issue is only in MOBILE DEVICES.** 
Site-Link: https://krishangsharma.github.io/Portfolio 
Any help is appreciated, Thanks

Comment: Hello _"UI/UX developer"_ you can just wrap your whole content in another `relative` element with `overflow: hidden` and `max-width: 100vw` but I would consider different document structure without need of any hotfix. Also you should use only one `h1` and make your web more _accessible_ (it lacks of some mandatory matters) and fix your layout on mobile (in my case it's pretty broken) to achieve _maximum satisfaction_ and become _the best web developer_ as you write on your website.

Comment: I can see that `nav-items` and `.square1` is causing the issue. Hope this helps to figure out the issue.

Comment: use the following CSS `*{outline: 1px solid red}` to check the design outlines, you will be able to verify if anything goes beyond the screen.

Comment: @Jax-p, thanks, that worked out for me. What do you mean by "Hotfix" and "Accessible". I didn't get that..?!